# Unique constraint violation

Tags: python, pyqt5, cx-oracle

I am using pyqt5 and cx_Oracle to insert records into a table in  oracle 11g express edition. When i insert the first record (no other records in table as yet) i get IntegrityError: ORA-00001: unique constraint (MCA.SYS_C007088) violated.
Despite the error the data is still inserted into the table.
Please can someone give me some guidance.

```
def genPaySlip():

dataList.append(int(uiMain.lineEdit_5.text()))
dataList.append(uiMain.lineEdit.text())
dataList.append(uiMain.lineEdit_2.text())
dataList.append(uiMain.lineEdit_3.text())
dataList.append(uiMain.lineEdit_4.text())
dataList.append(uiMain.lineEdit_6.text())
dataList.append(uiMain.lineEdit_9.text())
con = cx_Oracle.connect("mca", "mca", "localhost/xe")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("Insert into EmployeeDb values(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7)",(dataList[0:7]));
con.commit()
cur.close()
```

the sql table

```
create table Employeedb(EmployeeID number(5) primary key, Name varchar2(50), address varchar2(100), 
Branch varchar(10), Department varchar2(10),   Designation varchar2(20), PAN varchar2(10));
```

Comment: Okay well that all depends on exactly what is contained within your INSERT statement I would suggest storing it into a variable and then printing it out before you execute( ) it as without knowing exactly what it contains it is going to be next to impossible to tell you why you are getting your error.

Comment: Well I am getting string with numbers when I print it out.

Comment: I even tried using int() to convert it before storing it to the database. The strange thing is that I was getting the same issue even when I was using sqlite3.

Comment: Ahh forget it i figured out the problem i had an errant command in a for loop that was some how messing with the data. Thanks for your help Dennis Jensen